# Obj-C globally use NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a ViewController that prompts the FBFriendPickerViewController in which I, at selection, am returned with an NSArray containing the selection. Now I want to prompt and show a new ViewController using this selection information. I am new to Objective C, but I guess the solution is pretty simple. Here is my proposal:

ViewController2.h

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andSelection:(NSArray *)selection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *selectedParticipants;
```

ViewController2.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andSelection:(NSArray *)selection {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Split Bill", nil);
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor wuffBackgroundColor];
        self.selectedParticipants = selection;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelectedParticipants:(NSArray *)selectedParticipants {
    NSLog(@"setSelectedParticipants (%d)", [selectedParticipants count]);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"%d rowsInSection", [self.selectedParticipants count]);
    return [self.selectedParticipants count];
}
```

ViewController1.m

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        [[self friendPickerController] presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
            if (donePressed) {
                ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped
                                                                                andSelection:[self.friendPickerController selection]];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            }
            //[[self friendPickerController] clearSelection];
            }
         ];
    }
}
```

It seems, however, that the first setSelectedParticipants-log returns the correct amount of selected friends, but the numberOfRowsInSection-log returns 0.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never actually set anything in your setter!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in your setter:

```
- (void)setSelectedParticipants:(NSArray *)selectedParticipants {
    NSLog(@"setSelectedParticipants (%d)", [selectedParticipants count]);
}
```

You will notice that you never actually set the value for the instance variable backing the property, in this case, the default is `_selectedParticipants`. So, to fix, simply add the following line to your setter:

```
_selectedParticipants = selectedParticipants;
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: That makes sense. At first I tried (inside setSelectedParticipants) to do a `self.selectedParticipants = selectedParticipants`, which caused a loop, so I figured it was a kind of callback function. But since I have synthesized my property as _selectedParticipants it makes sense. The transition from PHP to Obj-C might take some time :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this function from your code

```
- (void)setSelectedParticipants:(NSArray *)selectedParticipants {
    NSLog(@"setSelectedParticipants (%d)", [selectedParticipants count]);
}
```

You are already set the selectedParticipants in init method

Comment: Nothing says he should "remove" it - it just needs to be fixed to actually set the underlying variable.

Comment: I was suggesting an easy fix. As i mentioned in my post "he is already setting array in his init function".